# Range constraint and variable management when passing information from macro to userform to worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I've built a userform that allows modification of a macro-generated string before it becomes part of a new spreadsheet. As written, I have one worry about how resilient it will be.

The form has a single textbox called `CourseDescription` into which a string value `strBundleDescription` is dumped:

```
frmDescriptionReview.CourseDescription = strBundleDescription
frmDescriptionReview.CourseDescription.MultiLine = True
frmDescriptionReview.CourseDescription.WordWrap = True
frmDescriptionReview.Show
```

The user can then edit the text as needed and press OK to pass the text to the spreadsheet being created.

On clicking OK, the modified string is placed in `Range("B7")` of the spreadsheet:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    Dim strValue As String

    strValue = CourseDescription.Value
    If strValue <> "" Then
        Range("B7").Value = strValue
    End If
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

This works so far in practice, but I've had unexplained focus issues before. I am concerned that the focus might in some (unknown) circumstance shift to another open worksheet and the text will be pasted where it does not belong.

**My question:** Am I right to want a more defined location, or will a simple range definition like the one above be adequate? And if a more defined location is advised, is there a way to pass information like the `wkbSaba` and `shtCourse` values without making public variables?

All potential solutions I found involved some form of public variable, but on principle (rightly or wrongly) I'm trying to avoid public variables when information will only be used in one function (as in this case).

---

**Full Code, as requested:** This is the the full macro code as it stands. The call for `frmDescriptionReview` is about 3/4 of the way down under the comment tag "'enter base information for Bundle Description".

I'm going to try the Property call as you suggest, which is something I did not know about, and had not seen when web searching for ways to pass data to a userform. So much to learn! It certainly looks like the variables could be passed that way.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransferData()


'***************************************
' TO USE THIS MACRO:
' 1. Make sure that all information for the bundle is included
'    on the 'km notification plan' and 'bundle details (kbar)' tabs
'    of the Reporting_KMFramework.xlsx
' 2. Select the bundle name on the 'km notification plan' tab.
' 3. Start the macro and it should create the basis of the Saba
'    form
' 4. Read through the entire form, especially the bundle
'    description, to be sure it is complete and accurate.
'***************************************


'establish variables

    Dim iRow As Integer

    Dim sTxt As String
    Dim sTxt2 As String
    Dim sBundleName As String
    Dim sNumber As String

    Dim aSplit() As String
    Dim aSplit2() As String
    Dim aBundleSplit() As String
    Dim aNumberSplit() As String

    Dim wkbFramework As Workbook
    Dim wkbSaba As Workbook

    Dim shtPlan As Worksheet
    Dim shtCourse As Worksheet

    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim vBundleName As Variant

    Dim lLoop As Long


'set initial values for variables

    'find current row number
        iRow = ActiveCell.Row

    'remember locations of current data
        Set wkbFramework = ActiveWorkbook
        Set shtPlan = ActiveSheet
            'Set rngSelect = Range("B" & iRow)

    'select bundle name
        vBundleName = shtPlan.Range("B" & iRow).Value
        vData = vBundleName
        sBundleName = shtPlan.Range("B" & iRow).Value

    'find and save course names for the bundle
        Sheets(2).Select
        sTxt = Find_Range(vBundleName, Columns("B"), xlValues).Offset(0, 1).Value 'course names from Detail tab
        sTxt2 = Find_Range(vBundleName, Columns("B"), xlValues).Offset(0, 2).Value 'course numbers from Detail tab

    'open new Saba Form
        Workbooks.Add Template:= _
        "C:\Documents and Settings\rookek\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates\Bundle_SabaEntryForm_KM.xltm"

    'remember locations of Saba form
        Set wkbSaba = ActiveWorkbook
        Set shtCourse = ActiveSheet


'move data into new Saba form

'paste bundle name
    wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B5").Value = vData

'Transfer bundle number
    vData = wkbFramework.Sheets(shtPlan.Name).Range("E" & iRow).Value
    sNumber = vData
    Dim aNumber() As String
    aNumber = Split(sNumber, "-")
    wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B6").Value = vData


'create  names to use in the bundle description and (later) in naming the file

    'Establish additional variables
        Dim strDate As String
        Dim strName1 As String
        Dim strName2 As String
        Dim strName3 As String
        Dim strName4 As String
        Dim strName5 As String

        Dim aTechSplit() As String
        Dim aCourse() As String

        Dim iTech As Integer
        'Dim iBundle As Integer
        Dim iCourse As Integer


    vData = wkbFramework.Sheets(shtPlan.Name).Range("L" & iRow).Value

    aCourse = Split(sTxt, Chr(10))
    iCourse = UBound(aCourse)
    aTechSplit = Split(vData, " ")
    iTech = UBound(aTechSplit)
    aBundleSplit = Split(sBundleName, " ")
    aNumberSplit = Split(sNumber, "-")
    strName1 = aBundleSplit(0)
    strName2 = aBundleSplit(1)
    If UBound(aNumberSplit) > 1 Then
        strName3 = aNumberSplit(UBound(aNumberSplit) - 1) & aNumberSplit(UBound(aNumberSplit))
    End If
    strName3 = Right(strName3, Len(strName3) - 1)
    strName4 = aTechSplit(0) & " "
    strName5 = aCourse(0)

    For lLoop = 1 To iTech - 1
            strName4 = strName4 & aTechSplit(lLoop) & " "
    Next lLoop

    If iCourse > 1 Then
        For lLoop = 1 To iCourse - 1
                strName5 = strName5 & ", " & aCourse(lLoop)
        Next lLoop
        strName5 = strName5 & ", and " & aCourse(iCourse)
    End If

    If iCourse = 1 Then
        strName5 = strName5 & ", and " & aCourse(iCourse)
    End If

    strName5 = Replace(strName5, " Technical Differences", "")
    strName5 = Replace(strName5, " Overview", "")
    strName5 = Replace(strName5, " Technical Presales for ATCs", "")
    strName5 = Replace(strName5, " Technical Presales for STCs", "")
    strName5 = Replace(strName5, " Technical Presales", "")


'enter base information for Bundle Description
    Dim strBundleDescription As String
    strBundleDescription = "This Knowledge Maintenance bundle covers recent technology changes that may affect " & strName4 & "environments. Topics covered by this bundle include the enhancements and features introduced with " & strName5 & "."
    'wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B7").Value = strBundleDescription

    frmDescriptionReview.CourseDescription = strBundleDescription
    frmDescriptionReview.CourseDescription.MultiLine = True
    frmDescriptionReview.CourseDescription.WordWrap = True
    frmDescriptionReview.Show


'transfer tech and track
    wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B8").Value = vData


'transfer product GA date
    vData = wkbFramework.Sheets(shtPlan.Name).Range("G" & iRow).Value
    wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B9").Value = vData


'transfer bundle notification date
    vData = wkbFramework.Sheets(shtPlan.Name).Range("D" & iRow).Value
    wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B10").Value = vData


'set audience type
    If aNumber(UBound(aNumber)) = "SA" Then
        wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B11").Value = "Internal, Partner, Customer"
    Else
        wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B11").Value = "Internal, Partner"
    End If


'set Education Manager
    frmEducationManagerEntry.EducationManagers.MultiLine = True
    frmEducationManagerEntry.EducationManagers.WordWrap = True
    frmEducationManagerEntry.Show


'set EPG
    wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B13").Value = "N/A (KM course reuse)"


'set Test information to N/A
    wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("A22:B22").Value = "N/A"


'enter course names
    aSplit = Split(sTxt, Chr(10)) 'if there is more than one course, this establishes a number and location for each

    If UBound(aSplit) > 4 Then

        'add rows equal to the difference between ubound and 5
            wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("A21", "B" & 21 + (UBound(aSplit) - 5)).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Insert

    End If

    For lLoop = 0 To UBound(aSplit)
            wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B" & 17 + lLoop).Value = aSplit(lLoop)
    Next lLoop


'enter course numbers
    aSplit2 = Split(sTxt2, Chr(10)) 'if there is more than one course, this establishes a number and location for each

    For lLoop = 0 To UBound(aSplit2)
            wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("A" & 17 + lLoop).Value = Trim(aSplit2(lLoop))
    Next lLoop


'save and close Saba form

        With wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name)

            Dim SaveAsDialog As FileDialog

            strDate = Date
            strDate = Replace(strDate, "/", ".")

            Set SaveAsDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

            With SaveAsDialog
              .Title = "Choose a file location and file name for your new Saba form"
              .AllowMultiSelect = False
              .InitialFileName = strName1 & strName2 & "_SabaEntryForm_" & strName3 & ".xlsx"
              '.InitialFileName = sSavelocation & "\" & strName3 & "\" & aBundleSplit(0) & aBundleSplit(1) & "_" & strName3 & "_SabaEntryForm" & ".xlsx"
              .Show
              .Execute
            End With

            wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).PrintOut

            wkbSaba.Close

        End With


' Return focus to Plan sheet
    shtPlan.Activate


End Sub
```

---

**Addition of Property code fails**

I tried adding code based on the property link shared in the comments, but running the code results in a Compile error: Method or data member not found.  The complete userform code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private wkbLocation As Workbook
Private shtLocation As Worksheet

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()

    Unload Me
    End

End Sub

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    Dim strValue As String

    strValue = CourseDescription.Value
    If strValue <> "" Then
        wkbLocation.Sheets(shtLocation).Range("B7").Value = strValue
    End If
    Unload Me

End Sub

Property Let MyProp(wkbSaba As Workbook, shtCourse As Worksheet)

    wkbLocation = wkbSaba
    shtLocation = shtCourse

End Property
```

And the call for the userform now looks like this:

```
'enter base information for Bundle Description
    Dim strBundleDescription As String
    strBundleDescription = "This Knowledge Maintenance bundle covers recent technology changes that may affect " & strName4 & "environments. Topics covered by this bundle include the enhancements and features introduced with " & strName5 & "."
    'wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B7").Value = strBundleDescription

    Dim frmDescriptionReview As UserForm3

    Set frmDescriptionReview = New UserForm3
    frmDescriptionReview.MyProp = "Pass to form"
    frmDescriptionReview.CourseDescription = strBundleDescription
    frmDescriptionReview.CourseDescription.MultiLine = True
    frmDescriptionReview.CourseDescription.WordWrap = True
    frmDescriptionReview.Show
```

When I run the code, I get a Compile error: Method or data member not found, highlighting `.MyProp`. Help says this error means I misspelled the object or member name, or specified a collection index that is out of range.  I checked the spelling, and MyProp is exactly how I spelled it in both locations. I don't think I'm specifying a collection am I? None are explicitly defined. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am concerned that the focus might in some (unknown) circumstance
>   shift to another open worksheet and the text will be pasted where it
>   does not belong.

Not really sure what you are asking.  But you can further define your range variable by using:

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Value = strValue
```

or

```
Workbooks(wkbSaba).Worksheets(shtCourse).Range("B7").Value = strValue
```

That will ensure it goes to the right workbook and worksheet.  I'm not sure why you think you need public variables?

EDIT:

**UserForm Code:**

```
Private wsSheet As Worksheet

Property Let SetWorksheet(wsSheetPass As Worksheet)
    Set wsSheet = wsSheetPass
End Property

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    Dim strValue As String

    strValue = CourseDescription.Value
    If strValue <> "" Then
        wsSheet.Range("B7").Value = strValue
    End If
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

**Calling Module:**

```
Dim wsSheetToPass As Worksheet

Set wsSheetToPass = Workbooks(wkbSaba).Worksheets(shtCourse)

frmDescriptionReview.SetWorksheet = wsSheetToPass
```

Comment: I had tried using the second version you suggest before I posting this question.  However, since that code is used in the userform code, not the macro itself, the compiler throws "variable not defined" on that line (for wkbSaba and shtCourse variables). Research suggested that using public variables for those two values would solve that problem.

Comment: I doubt you need to use public variables if you dont want too, however there is no harm in doing so.  Can you post all of your code please.  I need to see how you are calling the userform.

Comment: You can use a property to pass the argument [see here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/07/22/passing-arguments-to-a-userform/)

Comment: Also see [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=470) for passing arguments via a sub routine

Comment: Your edit got me on the right track.  When I added your code and ran it I got a Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch at `Set wsSheetToPass = Workbooks(wkbSaba).Worksheets(shtCourse)`.  Replacing the equivalent with `wkbSaba.Worksheets(shtCourse.Name)` seems to fix that problem. Now I just have to get my head around what you did (and how that differs from how I tried to use the Property method). Thanks for your help! You have answered my question, and given me more to ponder (like eliminating the public variables I've used in past userforms).

Comment: @Karl, I thought your variables wkbSaba and shtCourse where strings.  You should be able to just use `Set wsSheetToPass = wkbSaba.shtCourse`

Answer (score 0):

As Reafidy states, creating a Property for the Userform and passing information to it would clearly be the right answer for passing variables to and from a userform.

Ideally what I want is to have the form very losely coupled with the module, and not touch the spreadsheet at all (so when appropriate I can pass information to the form from other modules, get the information returned, and place it where appropriate for the current module (which could be on an entirely different spreadsheet or in a completely different cell).

I found additional information on passing data with properties on the PeltierTech web site (http://peltiertech.com/Excel/PropertyProcedures.html) that helped me understand what Reafidy was doing so I couls start loosening the coupling between my code and my forms even more (which was my original intent for this question.

Adding the Get property allows the loose coupling I'm looking for, allowing me to both give and receive information without having to pass the spreadsheet data at all. So my call in the module now looks like this:

```
    'review and revise Description Text
    Dim DescriptionReview As New frmDescriptionReview

    With DescriptionReview
        .Description = strBundleDescription
        .Show
        strBundleDescription = .Description
    End With

    Unload DescriptionReview

'transfer description text
    wkbSaba.Sheets(shtCourse.Name).Range("B7").Value = strBundleDescription
```

and the code for the UserForm itself becomes much simpler, like this:

```
Option Explicit

Property Let Description(ByVal TextBeingPassed As String)
    Me.CourseDescription.Value = TextBeingPassed
End Property

Property Get Description() As String
    Description = Me.CourseDescription.Value
End Property

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
    End
End Sub
```